# Where is aclocal's search path

Tags: c, autotools, autoconf, automake

I get following message when I run  `automake --foreign --add-missing` for my C program compiling.

```
mylib/Makefile.am:1: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
mylib/Makefile.am:1:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
mylib/Makefile.am:1:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
mylib/Makefile.am:1:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
mylib/Makefile.am:1:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
```

This is my `configure.ac` whitch includs LT_INIT.

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([drive], [1], [admin@local])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/drive.c])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CC
LT_INIT
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
                src/Makefile
                mylib/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

also mylib/Makefile.am is here

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmylib.la      
libmylib_la_SOURCES = mylib.c   
include_HEADERS = mylib.h
```

Then where is aclocal’ srearch path and how can I write definition of LT_ININT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see aclocal’ srearch path with `aclocal --print-ac-dir`

It was `/opt/libtool/share/aclocal`

But there isn’t any resource without README.

In my case aclocal is installed different with automake

And there is some m4 related files in `/opt/automake/share/aclocal`

Then I made symbolic link to /`opt/automake/share/aclocal`

```
/opt/libtool/share/aclocal-> /opt/automake/share/aclocal
```

Now automake completes with no error.

Answer (score 4):

the error indicates missing package "LIBTOOL"

```
mylib/Makefile.am:1: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
```

just install it

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

Comment: This answer does not address the title question, "Where is `aclocal`'s search path?"  Moreover, although the recommended action might sometimes resolve an issue such as the OP describes, the OP already self-answered the question, over six years ago, with a different solution demonstrating that missing libtool in fact was not the issue in this case.  Your efforts would be more fruitfully devoted to answering questions that do not already have an accepted answer.